# Validate date in momemnt js with specified format

Tags: jquery, date, validation, momentjs

I am trying to validate using moment js, as shown below, it returns true, which is correct.

`moment("10/22/2021","MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid()`

But in some cases I get date or month part as just one digit, in those cases, it will return false. Can someone help me how to handle this condition.

`moment("4/22/2021","MM/DD/YYYY", true).isValid()`   --want this to return true

**Points to consider: I dont want to remove last parameter which is set to true for strict check. And date parameter can come with any serprator. (Means it can come like '3-22-2021', '2.12.2020', '2_12_2020'). So suggestion of splitting date based on serprator and adding 0 in front of date or month wont work.**
*Or if you can suggest how to find proper serprator will also be helpfule*

Answer (score 0):

You can use `toLocaleDateString` method to get a standard date in "MM/DD/YYYY" format but it will not work with "_", which you have to `replace`, below some examples for reference.

```js
let d = new Date("2-3-2011");

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());

d = new Date("2.3.2011");

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());

d = new Date("2/3/2011");

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());

d = new Date(("2_3_2011").replace(/_/g,"-"));

console.log(d.toLocaleDateString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering the fact that both `12/02/21XX` & `12/2/21XX` can be validated through `M/D/YYYY`. So you can use that & evaluate the format of the incoming date & pass it to the moment that does the rest.

```
import moment from "moment";
        const date = "10/22/2021";
        let dateFormat;
        if(date.includes("/")){
        dateFormat = 'M/D/YYYY';
        }else if(date.includes(".")){
        dateFormat = 'M.D.YYYY';
        }else if(date.includes("-")){
        dateFormat = 'M-D-YYYY';
        }else if(date.includes("_")){
        dateFormat = 'M_D_YYYY';
        }
        const date_item = moment(date, dateFormat, true).isValid();
        console.log(date_item)
```